# How to have exception validation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a newbie in rails and I'm stuck with this problem: I have a model named User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  EMAIL_REGEX = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i
  validates :first_name, :presence => true,:format => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/
  validates :last_name, :presence => true,:format => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
  validates :password, :presence => true
  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
end
```

with database attributes `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `hashed_password` and `encrypted_password`.

When I create new Object of User and saves it in the database there is no problem. NOW, here's the problem I want to edit attributes of my User Object EXCEPT email and password.

Once I  try to edit the record through edit of rails resource it flags an error that password should not be empty. I am planning to have an exemption of validation if the user wants to edit his/her information but I know that it is not a good practice.

Hoping to find the best answer.

Comment: The model design is wrong. I recommend you you to check the book http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: @Sabyasachi Ghosh, which part of the design is wrong? I assumed that is a One to One relationship..

Comment: You should use fields like password and confirm password and then generate the password section. else you need to provide the on: create option each place.

Answer (score 0):

For starters check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation - once this approach becomes unDRY (repeated more then 2-3 times) see http://apidock.com/rails/Object/with_options

Once you get more advanced you will want to try something in the lines of a form/service class and extract form/action-specific validations there - http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

...and welcome to rails :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
validates :password, :presence => true, on: :create
```

And in the user edit form add every field except email and password.

But thing is that while you are going to change the password, there is no validation on password. So when you are implementing the change_password section, you need handle it and nee to add the errors manually for the password.

Comment: validates :password, :presence => true, on: :create

My concern is when I will try to have an Edit action for email and password, my password field will not be validated since it will validated only on create. Am I right @Bachan Smruty? Thanks for the idea.

Comment: yes. That what I have shared in my edited answer. First thing, email you should not add it to edit page because it is unique for each user. Yes for password, you need to handle it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved! Im not sure if this is the best solution. Once I instantiate a User object I use the after_initialize then set updatePassword to true as a default value then in the edit action of User Object I set updatePassword to false so that it will be exempted in the validation. I also use the conditional validation for the updatePassword. :D Thanks for all the ideas!